# Iphone: Cannot see Image on imageview

Tags: iphone, image, imageview

I am trying to set an image into an imageview but it is not working, I set all the connection to the Interface Builder.

When I running the program, the debugger shows the following:

```
(lldb) po image
(UIImage *) $2 = 0x06ed2290 <UIImage: 0x6ed2290>
```

for the imageview it says:

```
(lldb) po self.imageView
(UIImageView *) $1 = 0x06eac5e0 <UIImageView: 0x6eac5e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6ead050>>
```

The image is set using this code:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }
```

But the image is not show.

Comment: As you can see in by the `po self.imageView` the frame of you imageview is `(0 0; 0 0);` which means its 0 pixels by 0 pixels thus any image placed in it will not show. Can you verify that the image is large then 0x0

Comment: Do you mean that my imageview is 0 0 ; 0 0? I checked that in my IB and the ImageView is 400, 200. I also tied it with onther picture. But it says the same. Do I have to set the frame somewhere?

Comment: It looks like something is either resetting the frame or you are replacing the imageview some where.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. I wrote into my ViewDidLoad "self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];" stupid ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 150, 150)];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Modify your code with this maybe it will help :)...
You havent added the Image frame have you ?

Comment: He set its imageview in interface builder, thus there is no need to create a new one.

Comment: Oh well didnt c the comment till now :) ... I think maybe hes not adding the image rite ??